# Google Analytics for Google Play app page

Tags: google-analytics, google-play

I want to analyze what search keywords people use to find my app in the Play store.

Is that possible? How can I do so?

Answer (score 7):

As of October 2013, you can link your Google Analytics and Google Play account to see views of your App's page and the resulting conversions to downloads.  See here: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2956981

Not quite keywords yet, but it's close!

Comment: Does the linked page still have the right information? I only see options pertaining to analytics in the apps themselves.

Answer (score 2):

As you don't have direct access to the source code of your App page there is no way to include the necessary JS and unfortunately Google doesn't provide any method to insert your tracking ID like in Google Code. So i don't think this is possible.

Have a look at this question here too: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/25859/can-google-analytics-analyze-usage-of-my-google-play-app-page

Comment: Thanks, Stefan. What about Google Play Store Campaign Tracking, if we don't use AdWords, will that work? https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/campaigns#google-play-tracking

Comment: I've never used it, have a look at this link: http://www.localytics.com/docs/android-market-campaign-analytics/

Comment: see answer below. Some tracking data is now available.