# How can I track impressions of my android app vs downloads on Google Play Store Website?

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-play

I have an app listed on the google play store website.  I have set up the app with event tracking using Google Analytics and I'm able to see events once users have downloaded the app.  My question is how, through google analytics, can I track impressions of my store listing page.

The goals I want to accomplish with this information is:

1. Track the number of impressions of the store listing page vs. downloads.
2. Track the referrer information of what was the page that brought them to the store.
3. Track any search terms used in the store that was queried for my app listing.

Comment: Take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13571608/google-analytics-for-google-play-app-page, Link your app with Google Analytics may help: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2956981

Comment: You found it.  I was looking for more information on this, thanks @Imskull.  You found the answer so I will select yours if you want.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Updating an old question, but I hope this will help others who stumble upon this.

Google launched analytics on user acquisition last year in the Play Store Developer Console. Just login to the console, select your application, then select the User Acquisition tab. The impressions and download stats will be available approx. 2-3 days later.

More info: http://techcrunch.com/2015/05/28/google-launches-improved-app-install-analytics-expands-service-to-ios/