# Is is possible to get keywords used to land on my Google play page?

Tags: google-analytics, google-play

Is it possible to get keywords that a user uses to land on my Google Play page. I have linked my Google Analytics and Google Play page, but is still not able to get this.

On my website, it get this data using Google Analytics. So I was wondering why google aint providing this on Play Store.

I do realise that this question was posted earlier - [Google Analytics for Google Play app page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13571608/google-analytics-for-google-play-app-page) . But that is a pretty old post(2012). So was wondering if Google has come up with some solution  recently.

Answer (score 1):

It appears this still isn't possible. [The answer provided by Stefan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13571845/896802) that you link still seems to hold true:

> you don't have direct access to the source code of your App page there is no way to include the necessary JS [to track keywords]

The closest you might get (and this may be a terrible idea since you may divert clicks from your Google Play storefront) is to create a landing page outside of Google Play, capture the search keywords there with GA + Webmaster tools, and then extrapolate.

Comment: Aint that pathetic... What could be Google's logic of not enabling this.. Anyways.. Thanks for the answer bro..  :)